# faster way to query on mongodb with aggregate framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there a faster way to query on MongoDB?
My data is something like this:

```
[{
        "c_custkey": 1,
        "c_name": "Customer#000000001",
        "c_address": "IVhzIApeRb",
        "c_city": "MOROCCO  0",
        "c_nation": "MOROCCO",
        "c_region": "AFRICA",
        "lineorders": [{
                    "lo_orderkey": 164711,
                    "lo_linenumber": 1,
                    "lo_custkey": 1,
                    "lo_partkey": 82527,
                    "lo_suppkey": 1848,
                    "lo_quantity": 34,
                    "lo_extendedprice": 5132368,
                    "orderdate": [{
                        "d_datekey": 19920426,
                        "d_date": "April 26, 1992",
                        "d_dayofweek": "Monday",
                        "d_month": "April",
                        "d_year": 1992,
                        "d_yearmonthnum": 199204,
                    }],
                    "part": [{
                        "p_partkey": 82527,
                        "p_name": "steel tomato",
                        "p_mfgr": "MFGR#4",
                        "p_category": "MFGR#45",
                        "p_brand1": "MFGR#452",
                    }],
                    "supplier": [{
                        "s_city": "MOZAMBIQU8",
                        "s_nation": "MOZAMBIQUE",
                        "s_region": "AFRICA",
                    }]
                }, {
                    "lo_orderkey": 164711,
                    "lo_linenumber": 2,
                    "lo_custkey": 1,
                    "lo_partkey": 26184,
                    "lo_suppkey": 1046,
                    "lo_orderdate": 19920426,
                    "lo_quantity": 15,
                    "lo_extendedprice": 1665270,
                    "orderdate": [{
                        "d_datekey": 19920426,
                        "d_date": "April 26, 1992",
                        "d_dayofweek": "Monday",
                        "d_month": "April",
                        "d_year": 1992,
                        "d_yearmonthnum": 199204,
                    }],
                    "part": [{
                        "p_partkey": 26184,
                        "p_name": "chartreuse green",
                        "p_mfgr": "MFGR#2",
                        "p_category": "MFGR#23",
                        "p_brand1": "MFGR#2329",
                    }],
                    "supplier": [{
                        "s_suppkey": 1046,
                        "s_city": "SAUDI ARA2",
                        "s_nation": "SAUDI ARABIA",
                        "s_region": "MIDDLE EAST",
                    }]
                },
```

And I'm querying this way:

```
db.customer.aggregate([
   { "$match":{
       "$and":[
          {"lineorder.orderdate.d_year":{"$gte":1992}},
          {"lineorder.orderdate.d_year":{"$lte":1997}},
          {"lineorder.supplier.s_region":"ASIA"},
          {"c_region":"ASIA"}
       ]
   }},
   { "$unwind":"$lineorder" },
   { "$match":{
       "$and":[
           {"lineorder.orderdate.d_year":{"$gte":1992}},
           {"lineorder.orderdate.d_year":{"$lte":1997}},
           {"lineorder.supplier.s_region":"ASIA"},
           {"c_region":"ASIA"}
       ]
    }},
   { "$project": {
       "lineorder.supplier.s_nation":1,
       "c_nation":1,"
       "lineorder.orderdate.d_year":1,
       "lineorder.lo_revenue":1
   }},
   { "$group":{
      "_id":{
          "s_nation":"$lineorder.supplier.s_nation",
          "c_nation":"$c_nation",
          "d_year": "$lineorder.orderdate.d_year"
      }, 
      "revenue": {"$sum": "$lineorder.lo_revenue"}
   }},
   { "$sort":{"_id.d_year":1, revenue:-1}}
]).toArray()
```

The reason I have to "match" two times is because when I do it once it returns all documents that match my condition, and not all "lineorders" inside a document that have one match satisfies it, and if I do the "unwind" before it takes a lot of time. My database have 2 GB of this kind of data.

Comment: Are the key fields indexed?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ No, they aren't, but the query dont references to the keys.